# What to pass as parameter for ConfigurationSection class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API(.Net-6 version).To access a Connection string, I need to configure services in Program.cs as below:

[image]

But, while creating an Instance I need to pass a parameter. Because **ConfigurationSection** Has a constructor as below.

[image]

The problem is I don't know what to pass as parameter. It requires - Configuration root and path to the section. I don't know what it is!

Comment: Why are you trying to create a `ConfigurationSection` in the first place? You don't need that to read settings

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for get the connection string, yo can do that in you Program.cs class :

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

And in you appsettings.json, you need somthings like that :

```
{
   /* ... */
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "you connection string"
   },
   /* ... */
}
```

**Edit :**
Here a complet example of a more complicated Settings class.

The `EmailSettings.cs` class :

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Configurations
{
    public class EmailSettings
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool EnableSSL { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The corresponding part in the `appsettings.json` file:

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "EnableSSL": true,
    "UserName": "example@gmail.com",
    "Password": "12345"
},
```

And the registration of the settings class in the `Program.cs` class:

```
builder.Services.Configure<EmailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
```

After that, you can call the settings class with dependency injection like that :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private EmailSettings _emailSettings;
    
    public HomeController(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings)
    {
        _emailSettings= emailSettings.Value; // Don't forget the .Value
    }
    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get the configuration items like that
        string getConfig = _emailSettings.Host;
        return View();
    }
}
```